# React Navigation v4 remove Bottom navigator

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to remove my bottom Tab navigator just for my `Content` screen . Is this possible . Please can someone help me . I am trying to remove it from my stack navigator.

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
//React Navigation imports
import {createStackNavigator, TransitionPresets} from 'react-navigation-stack'
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs'
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
import Content from '../Screens/Content'
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import GetStarted from '../Screens/GetStarted'
import Edit from '../Screens/Edit'

const ProfileNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Content: {
        screen: Content,
        navigationOptions:()=>{
            return {
                tabBarVisible:false,
            };
        }
    },
    GetStarted: GetStarted,
}
);

const SecondNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    EditBook: Edit
})
const NavigationBar = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Profile: {screen: ProfileNavigator, navigationOptions:{
        tabBarIcon : (tabInfo) =>{
            return <FontAwesome name="feed" color={tabInfo.tintColor} />
        }
    }},
    Settings: {screen: SecondNavigator, navigationOptions:{
        tabBarIcon : (tabInfo) =>{
            return <FontAwesome name="settings" color={tabInfo.tintColor} />
        },
        title: 'My Cookbook'   
    }},
},
{
    tabBarOptions:{
        activeTintColor: Colors.orange,
        inactiveTintColor: '#B1B1B1',
    },
})
export default createAppContainer(NavigationBar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one `SwitchNavigator` and inside it, you will construct your screens as you want with the navigators that you want too. I will use your code to show you what I mean.

```
import React from 'react';
//React Navigation imports
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Content from '../Screens/Content';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import GetStarted from '../Screens/GetStarted';
import Edit from '../Screens/Edit';

const NavigationBar = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        Profile: createBottomTabNavigator({
            screen: Edit,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: tabInfo => {
                    return (
                        <FontAwesome name='feed' color={tabInfo.tintColor} />
                    );
                },
            },
        }),
        Settings: createStackNavigator({
            screen: Content,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: tabInfo => {
                    return (
                        <FontAwesome
                            name='settings'
                            color={tabInfo.tintColor}
                        />
                    );
                },
                title: 'My Cookbook',
            },
        }),
        GetStarted: createStackNavigator({ screen: GetStarted }),
    },
    {
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: Colors.orange,
            inactiveTintColor: '#B1B1B1',
        },
    }
);
export default createAppContainer(NavigationBar);
```

When you navigate, you will use `navigation.navigate('KeyName')` where KeyName in that example is 'GetStarted', 'Settings', and 'Profile'. Note: the `BottomTabNavigator` is applied only for Profile key that is Edit screen.

Comment: Then the content screen won’t have the bottom navigation and everything else will which is what i want . Does this solve that problem

Comment: @DilhanBhagat Does that solved the problem? If yes select it as an answer to help someone else who is having this same problem